# Removing duplicate lines from file does not work correctly although using a set and strip()

Tags: python, file

Write a Python program that reads the contents of a text file called "input.txt," removes duplicate lines, and writes the unique lines to a new file called "output.txt." Consider lines to be duplicates if they have the same content, regardless of leading or trailing whitespace. (use context manager)

For example, if "input.txt" contains:

```
Hello, World!
Python is fun.
Python is fun.
   Python is fun.
```

After running the program, "output.txt" should contain:

```
Hello, World!
Python is fun.
```

Handle errors properly

for above question I am using following solution

```
def remove_duplicates(input_file, output_file):
    try:
        with open(input_file, 'r') as in_file:
            lines = in_file.readlines()

        unique_lines = set(line.strip() for line in lines if line.strip())

        with open(output_file, 'w') as out_file:
            for line in unique_lines:
                out_file.write(f"{line}\n")

        print("Unique lines written to output.txt successfully.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error: input.txt not found.")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Error: Permission denied while opening the file.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Usage
remove_duplicates('input.txt', 'output.txt')
```

But it's giving following output

```
Hello, World!
Python is fun.
Python is fun.
```

Can someone please tell what's wrong in my output and modify my code please.

Comment: Is the input `'Hello, World! Python is fun. Python is fun. Python is fun.'` in a single line or line by line

Comment: Have you checked the contents of input.txt?

Comment: Also note that sets are **not ordered**. If you expect an output with similar order don't depend on set ordering.

Comment: Please modify your code to hard-code the input lines. If that fixes it, your problem is in reading your lines. Also, for quick debugging, use `repr()` to format something to resemble Python syntax, which makes it easier to find trailing whitespace, for example. Also, running this in a debugger would help, try to find a video tutorial as introduction.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code an input shown. Running the code with the given content for `input.txt` results in an `output.txt` containing the lines `Hello, World!` and `Python is fun.` exactly once (though in arbitrary order). Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

After lines 4, put this code and see the result:

```
for line in lines:
    print(repr(line))
```

Maybe there are hidden characters that cuases this problem. It's impossible that the variable of this code has a duplicate value:

```
unique_lines = set(line.strip() for line in lines if line.strip())
```

Answer (score -1):

If you create a set from all of the input lines, the output may not be in the correct order. You should construct the set as you process each individual line.

You could consider doing it this way:

```
with open('input.txt') as indata, open('output.txt', 'w') as outdata:
    uniquelines = set()
    for line in map(str.strip, indata):
        if line not in uniquelines:
            print(line, file=outdata)
            uniquelines.add(line)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def remove_duplicates(input_file, output_file):
try: 
    with open(input_file, 'r') as in_file:
        lines = in_file.readlines()
        
    unique_lines = []
    for i in lines:
        i = i.strip()
        if i not in unique_lines:
            unique_lines.append(i)

    with open(output_file, 'w') as out_file:
        for line in unique_lines:
            out_file.write(f"{line}\n")

    print("Unique lines written to output.txt successfully.")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Error: input.txt not found.")
except PermissionError:
    print("Error: Permission denied while opening the file.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

## Usage

remove_duplicates('input.txt', 'output.txt')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).